# Retrieving drop down list items from list of controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, list

I am attempting to retrieve a `ListItemCollection` from a `List` of controls. This `List` contains many controls of different types - `DropDownList`, `Label`, `TextBox`.

I would like to retrieve all `ListItem` from all the `DropDownList` controls contained in the original `List` of controls.

My thought process so far has been to extract all of the `DropDownList` controls into a new list, and iterate though this to pull out each `ListItem` - however, every `DropDownList` control is coming up with 0 items

```
ControlCollection cList = pnlContent.Controls;

List<DropDownList> ddlList = new List<DropDownList>();
foreach (Control c in cList)
{
    if (c.GetType() == new DropDownList().GetType())
    {
        ddlList.Add((DropDownList)c);
    }
}

ListItemCollection itemCollection = new ListItemCollection();
foreach (DropDownList ddl in ddlList)
{
    foreach(ListItem li in ddl.Items)
    {
        itemCollection.Add(li);
    }
}
```

I'm sure this is the wrong (and massively inefficient) way of doing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could get a list of all the ListItems with Linq - pnlContent.Controls.OfType<DropDownList>().SelectMany(x => x.Items.Cast<ListItem>()); However, I think the issue you are having with the lists being empty might be related to the point in the lifetime of the page that your doing the iteration.

Comment: Everybody is showing you different ways of getting the right controls, but I understand that this is not the real problem. Your problem is the fact that the controls are empty. you should try to set a breakpoint just after the definition of your cList var and inspect the controls in the collection to see if they contain some items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do:

```
public IEnumerable<ListItem> GetListItems(ControlCollection controls)
{
    return controls.OfType<DropDownList>().SelectMany(c => c.Items.OfType<ListItem>());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I currently do not have an installation where I can test this, but as a line of thought I would use Linq to do this.

Here is an example that you should be able to use;

```
var type = new DropDownList().GetType();

var listOfControl = from c in pnlContent.Controls
                    where c.GetType() == type
                    select ((DropDownList)c).Items;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var ddlList = cList.OfType<DropDownList>();


 ListItemCollection itemCollection = new ListItemCollection();
 // option 1
 var temp = ddlList.Select(ddl => ddl.Items.Cast<ListItem>()).SelectMany(li => li).ToArray();
 itemCollection.AddRange(temp);
 // or option 2
 var temp = ddlList.Select(ddl => ddl.Items.Cast<ListItem>()).SelectMany(li => li);
 foreach (var listItem in temp)
 {
     itemCollection.Add(listItem);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        comboBox1.Items.Add(button1);
        comboBox1.Items.Add(button2);
        comboBox1.Items.Add(dateTimePicker1);
        comboBox1.Items.Add(checkBox1);

        comboBox2.Items.Add(button3);
        comboBox2.Items.Add(button4);
        comboBox2.Items.Add(dateTimePicker2);
        comboBox2.Items.Add(checkBox2);

        comboBox3.Items.Add(button5);
        comboBox3.Items.Add(dateTimePicker3);
        comboBox3.Items.Add(checkBox3);
        comboBox3.Items.Add(checkBox4);

        List<ComboBox> ddlList = new List<ComboBox>();
        foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
        {
            if (c is ComboBox)
            {
                ddlList.Add((ComboBox)c);
            }
        }

        List<Control> itemCollection = new List<Control>();

        foreach (ComboBox ddl in ddlList)
        {
            foreach (var li in ddl.Items)
            {
                itemCollection.Add((Control)li);
            }
        }
```